# Suggest tag synonym: [category] and [categories]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) should be the main tag, and [categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/categories) should be a synonym and redirected to the first one. The two tags on Stack Overflow have a quite similar description:

[category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) descripton:

> A **category** is a grouping of information.

[categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/categories) description:

> **Categories** are grouping of information.

---

Although there are only 46 posts with both tags, that could be a result of choice while choosing the tags and not using synonyms.

The first 5 related tags are equal on both tags, and one is related to the other. I'm posting here because i don't have enough rep.