# Synonym suggestions for plurals

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The 5 upvote barrier stops me from suggesting directly, so here are ideas of tags that could be synonyms, for anyone who still needs the Synonymizer badge.

- [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages) -> [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/package/synonyms
- [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders) -> [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252105/) - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/folder/synonyms
- [pointcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcuts) -> [pointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcut) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pointcut/synonyms
- [aspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspects) -> [aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspect) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/aspect/synonyms
- [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines) -> [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/line/synonyms
- [margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margins) -> [margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/margin/synonyms
- [pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixels) -> [pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pixel/synonyms
- [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions) -> [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion) (plural use slightly more than singular) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assertion/synonyms
- [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) -> [shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shortcut/synonyms
- [categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/categories) -> [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303227) - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/category/synonyms
- [two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-columns) - > [multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multiple-columns/synonyms

The most visible functionality impacted by the artificial diversity is maybe the click on the tag name to reveal similar questions. 
Possibly the calculation of related questions would also get more meaningful results, though that is hard to prove.

Comment: assertions, folders, packages - these are a bit more than _colloquially_ pluralized, probably better left with the plural being the tag. Looking at some of the others (e.g. shortcuts) where it seems the reasoning for the tag being applied is kinda random (maybe it should just go altogether).

Comment: Do you think askers, answerers, or reviewers would be able to pick the 'right' tag in those cases you consider more than pluralized? Can a post be mistagged at all using the respective alternative tag? Would anyone even notice the 'wrong' one was picked?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275672, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/30032

Answer (score 2):

I only have one votes to give, but some of these look like eradicating plural for the sakes of it. I agree with a fews but some of these tag seems like it needs closer inspections, not synonym straight aways.

But, just my two cent.

Comment: Sure, it is just minor housekeeping to improve metadata just a tiny bit. I believe you can find questions using both variants for all of those. And I believe all of them are truly just plurals, not separate concepts. If you could pick the most striking example of which one is not synonym, that may help. Or maybe you refer to the tag wikis, which may have created independently of each other. Not sure if such creative differences would be relevant here at all, tag wikis change over time.